# Variable changed value suddenly after Loop

Tags: c++, variables

I have a problem with matrix called `nablist`. When I printed `nablist` in first print the `nablist` was absolutely right, but when I printed it again the values were totally wrong. I believe that the problem is in line:

```
nablist[i,nnab[i]]=j
```

Because I tried to put a pointer as index. Any idea?

I have the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>         

int main(int argc, char **argv) 

int n=902; 
int i,j;
int* nnab=new int[nmax];
int* nablist=new int[nmax,6];


 for (i=0;i<n;i++)
 {
   nnab[i]=0;
   for (j=0;j<6;j++)
   {
      nablist[i,j]=0;
   }
 }

   for (i=0;i<n-1;i++)
   {
      for (j=i+1;j<n;j++)
      {   
       nnab[i]=nnab[i]+1;  
       nablist[i,nnab[i]]=j;
       cout<<nablist[i,nnab[i]]<<endl;  //first print
      } 
    }

    for (i=0;i<n-1;i++)
    {
     cout<<nablist[i,nnab[i]]<<endl;  //second print
    }
 }
```

---

Thanks for your answers. Yes the problem was that I need to use multiple pairs of square brackets. I tried to use `int (*ptr)[5] = new int[5][10];` but I had an error. I want to define a 2D array with n rows and m columns. I want to use a text file to read the n,m variables in order to define the 2D array..How can I do that? Do you understand what I mean?
Thank you

Comment: Please provide a code that compiles and with only the necessary to show your issue.

Comment: the `[]` operator only takes **one argument**.

Answer (score 2):

Try to fix the following warnings:

```
 % g++ test.cpp -Wall
test.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
test.cpp:13:27: warning: left operand of comma operator has no effect [-Wunused-value]
 int* nablist=new int[nmax,6];
                           ^
test.cpp:21:17: warning: left operand of comma operator has no effect [-Wunused-value]
       nablist[i,j]=0;
                 ^
test.cpp:30:24: warning: left operand of comma operator has no effect [-Wunused-value]
        nablist[i,nnab[i]]=j;
                        ^
test.cpp:31:30: warning: left operand of comma operator has no effect [-Wunused-value]
        cout<<nablist[i,nnab[i]]<<endl;  //first print
                              ^
test.cpp:37:28: warning: left operand of comma operator has no effect [-Wunused-value]
      cout<<nablist[i,nnab[i]]<<endl;  //second print
```

You should read the documentation about the comma operator. Wikipedia says:

> In the C and C++ programming languages, the comma operator
>   (represented by the token ,) is a binary operator that evaluates its
>   first operand and discards the result, and then evaluates the second
>   operand and returns this value (and type).

And search on the Internet how to do a 2-dimensional array in C/C++.

Answer (score 0):

I think I know where is the problem.
When you want to make 2D array, you need to use multiple pairs of square brackets:
`int arr[10][10];`

Same thing when you want to access object in array:
`arr[2][3] = 0;`

And you must use `new` like that:
<s>`int (*ptr)[5] = new int[5][10];`</s>
`int (*ptr)[10] = new int[5][10];`

If it's 3D array, it will be
<s>`int (*ptr)[7][8] = new int[7][8][9];`</s>
`int (*ptr)[8][9] = new int[7][8][9];`

Last thing: don't forget to delete arrays created with `new` when you're no longer need them:

```
int *p = new int[1000];

// ...

delete [] p;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Yes the problem was that I need to use multiple pairs of square brackets. I tried to use int (*ptr)[5] = new int[5][10]; but I had an error. I want to define a 2D array with n rows and m columns. I want to use a text file to read the n,m variables in order to define the 2D array..How can I do that? Do you understand what I mean? Thank you

Comment: Oh, my mistake. Fixed it. When you create multidimensional arrays with `new` you need to remove leftmost pair of square brackets. `>> I want to use a text file...` Open a new question about it. One post - one question.